# shell: decimal numbers programming

Tags: linux, shell

i have this program which compute the sum of maximus of each row, but it doesn't work for decimal numbers, thanks for help

```
#!/bin/sh
#script.sh
fichier=$1
old_IFS=$IFS
somme=0
while IFS='$\n' read -r ligne; do
index=0
max=0
IFS=' '
read -a array <<<"$ligne"
nb=${#array[*]}
   while [ "$index" -lt "$nb" ]
   do 
      if [[ "${array[$index]}" > "$max" ]]; then
      max="${array[$index]}"
      fi        
      index=$(($index+1))
   done
somme=$(($somme+$max))
done < "$fichier"

echo $somme
IFS=$old_IFS

exit 0
```

Comment: BASH cannot do decimal number arithmetic. Use `awk` or `bc`.

Comment: `perl -MList::Util=max -lawnE '$sum += max(@F); END {say $sum}' input`